# Convert boost random code to class object

Tags: c++, boost, random

I’m trying to create a random number generator object that will exist during the application’s lifetime.  I wish to have a single public interface function called number_generator() which should return a random number when called.

Please note that the main() function below, which compiles fine, produces good random numbers but at the bottom is the class that I just can’t get to work:

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 

int main(int c, char** argv) 
{
  // Define a uniform random number distribution of integer values between MIN and MAX
  const int MIN = 1; 
  const int MAX = 2147483648;

  typedef boost::uniform_int<> distribution_type; 
  typedef boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, distribution_type> gen_type; 

  distribution_type dist(MIN, MAX); 
  boost::mt19937 gen; 
  gen_type number_generator(gen, dist); 
  gen.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));  // seed with the current time 

  // output random ints
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) 
    std::cout << number_generator() << std::endl;

}
```

Here’s the problem, due to limited C++ knowledge, I just can’t get a public interface to number_generator():

```
#ifndef _random_generator_H_
#define _random_generator_H_

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

#include <ctime> 

class random_generator
{
public:
  random_generator() /* : MIN(1), MAX(2147483648)*/
  {
    distribution_type dist(MIN, MAX); 
    boost::mt19937 gen; 

    gen_type number_generator(gen, dist); 
    gen.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));  // seed with the current time 
  }
private:
  // define a uniform random number distribution of integer values between MIN and MAX
  int MIN; 
  int MAX;

  typedef boost::uniform_int<> distribution_type; 
  typedef boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, distribution_type> gen_type; 

};

#endif
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with the number_generator() in main? You probably want to wadd a public method like `double next()` and call that in your class

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The result of `std::time` is generally in seconds, which means if someone were to create two instances of your class within the same second both RNGs will be seeded identically; a typically undesirable scenario. Consider using [`boost::random_device`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/random/random_device.html) instead to generate the seed.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
class random_generator
```

you initialise a generator in the constructor:

```
 gen_type number_generator(gen, dist);
```

and then promptly forget about it.
Make it a *member* variable if you want to *remember* it.

```
class random_generator
{
    //...
    private:
    //...
    gen_type number_generator;
};
```

You were happy as Larry in `main` using

```
std::cout << number_generator() << std::endl;
```

So, put a suitable member in the class:

```
class random_generator
{
    public:
    //...
    int next()
    {
        return number_generator();
    }

    private:
    //...
    gen_type number_generator;
};
```

Then you can use it all in main:

```
//relevant includes

int main(int c, char** argv) 
{
  random_generator numbers;
  // output random ints
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) 
    std::cout << numbers.next() << std::endl;

}
```

BTW  consider learning how to put implementations in cpp files, instead of headers.

Comment: From me you don't get a +1 just for that, but it's the right thing to do.

Comment: The part that I'm stuck on is gen_type number_generator(gen, dist); and I'm still trying to absorb everyone's comments.  Thank you!

Comment: I used doctor love's suggestion and it worked wonderfully, sorry that I can't vote because I don't have a reputation yet.  But thank you once again!